# Auto Increment missing in phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I need some help with my phpMyAdmin

I recently migrated from XAMPP to laragon and my new phpMyAdmin is not showing auto increment...

Any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: Auto increment is for column! so how is the image is relevant? can try create a table?

Comment: do you even use phpmyadmin? do you ever reset your auto_increment?

Comment: yes a_i is for column but dont you usually reset it, or set it from operations table? it was there, now it's not anymore.... usually they show AUTO INCREMENT with some input field next to it... in my xampp it's located just where the ROW_FORMAT is located..

Comment: No for sure I do not use 'php my admin' and if your question is how to reset auto increment. So you need to truncate the table. or alert table and set autoincrement to 1.as  `ALTER TABLE <tableName> AUTO_INCREMENT = 1`

Comment: LOL :))) yup and i have like 89 tables ready to be resetted ... thanks for the help mate